# tfest :: too many parameters for chosen data size

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to find transfer function for some input data and output data using the code

```
Temperature = [zeros(1,153) 300*ones(1,47)];

out_temp = [zeros(1,147) ScopeData4.signals(1).values'];
N = 1; 
tfdata_tem = iddata(out_temp,Temperature,0.001);

sys = tfest(tfdata_tem,N);
```

but in the end I get the following error despite the fact that i have increased the number of samples and reduced the order to 1

There are too many parameters to estimate for chosen estimation data size. Reduce model order or use a larger data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is that your data set doesn't contain a rich enough set of frequencies for the underlying algorithm to estimate a model (of any order).

The iddata1 sample data set gives an example of what typical data should look like.
In particular, note that the input signal is comprised of many steps, occurring at non-regular intervals, unlike your data that has just one step.

```
load iddata1 z1;
plot(z1);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30271793/4826457) by [Phil Goddard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1998377/phil-goddard) shows in the figure, you need two column output values and input values. But the values in your programming are two row values. That means you need to change it into

```
Temperature = [zeros(1,153) 300*ones(1,47)]';

out_temp = [zeros(1,147) ScopeData4.signals(1).values']';

N = 1; 
tfdata_tem = iddata(out_temp,Temperature,0.001);

sys = tfest(tfdata_tem,N);
```